# Enable Migration error - object refreence, MigrationsDomainCommand

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a MVC 4 project and recently upgraded to EF 6.0. I have only one project which contains the models and dbcontext. I was unable to enable migrations, the errors are as follows:

> `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetPropertyValue[T](Project project, String propertyName)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String contextTypeName)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Googling for an answer for past 2 days, nothing seems to work.
Please help me.

Comment: There's a lot of related issues about Migrations pending in the working item. maybe some of those could be your own issue: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issues this week when my senior developer updated the solution to EF6.

After a 'Get latest' from source control, the migrations weren't working anymore.
A Visual Studio restart solved that problem. Probably the EF5 libraries were still in memory.

Comment: Restarting VS worked for me also, after just getting the latest sources from source control. However it was not related to upgrading to EF6

Comment: I can confirm this happens with TFS -> Get latest. TFS seems to do something to migrations in certain conditions. Never had this when I've used Git.

Comment: This week I had something similar happening when using GIT. An update-database didn't work after 'get latest'. Restarting Visual Studio solved this again.

Answer (score 1):

I saw someone saying that you need to run Visual Studio as an administrator. I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many suggestions and none of them worked. What worked for me:

**Check your folder path** that it contains all appropriate characters, for example **the name of the folder which my project was saved in, had an '&' symbol in it**. This messed up my migrations and updates like crazy.

I removed this symbol from the folder name and the issue was resolved.